# Is it possible to test if element is visible when set by CSS classes using Jasmine in Angular 2+?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have an element that becomes visible when another element is hovered over.  This is all handled in plain CSS, no Angular or JavaScript used.  Is it possible, using Jasmine, to see whether or not the element is visible when the mouse is hovering over the selected element?  I have seen other posts asking similar, and a lot of times the answer seems to be using Angular directives or coding the style change in JavaScript.  I don't want to do that, the pure CSS solution works great.  Here is my code so far:

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.wrapper .content {
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: black;
    font-size: 12px;
    left: 50%;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.wrapper:hover .content {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    Show the hidden element on hover
    <div class="content">I am now visible!</div>
</div>
```

**Jasmine Unit Test**

```
it('should display the hidden element when wrapper is hovered over', () => {
    const wrapper = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.wrapper'));
    const content = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.content'));
    let styles = window.getComputedStyle(content.nativeElement);

    wrapper.triggerEventHandler('mouseover', null);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(styles.visibility).toBe('visible');
});
```

The unit test fails saying it expects the `visibility` property to be `hidden`.

Comment: Why don't you get updated styles `styles = window.getComputedStyle(content.nativeElement);` after performing `fixture.detectChanges();`. You can try that.

Comment: @AmitChigadani, thanks for the reply!  I tried that and unfortunately it still returns `hidden`.  I am baffled because logically it should return `visible`.  Not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Ok one more try, Use `dispatchEvent` instead of `triggerEventHandler` like, `wrapper.dispatchEvent(new Event('mouseover'));`. This directly manipulates the `dom` as opposed to `debugElement`

Comment: Unit tests are for testing code and not CSS. This might be better done in the e2e testing with protractor.

Comment: @AmitChigadani, I tried that also and of course, no go :-(

Comment: @MMansour, yeah, you may be right.  If the logic is purely in the CSS, as this example is, then I think an e2e test would be best.  Thanks.